# SceneKit : Apply transformation on vertices

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, ios8, scenekit

I need to apply a transformation to all my vertices contained on a `SCNNode`.
Each `SCNNode` contains a **SCNMatrix4 transform** property.
I got also all vertices of my `SCNNode`.

```
 Vertex *currentVertex = [self.vectrices objectAtIndex:buff[index]];
 SCNNode *currentChildren = myNode;    
 Vertex *new = [Vertex new];

 new.x = (currentChildren.transform.m11 * currentVertex.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m12 * currentVertex.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m13 * currentVertex.z);
 new.y = (currentChildren.transform.m21 * currentVertex.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m22 * currentVertex.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m23 * currentVertex.z);
 new.z = (currentChildren.transform.m31 * currentVertex.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m32 * currentVertex.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m33 * currentVertex.z);
```

I got a strange resultant with wrong rotation and translation.
My calcul, is it correct ?

Answer (score 2):

`SCNMatrix4` is a 4x4 matrix, but here you're using it as 3x3 matrix. You're basically removing all translations and just keeping rotations and scale factors.
Take a look at `SCNMatrix4ToMat4` and `SCNVector4ToFloat4` (take `w=1`) and use SIMD to perform your transformations.

Comment: float w = (currentChildren.transform.m41 * currentVertex.x) + (currentChildren.transform.m42 * currentVertex.y) + (currentChildren.transform.m43 * currentVertex.z) + currentChildren.transform.m44;
                
                new.x = new.x / w;
                new.y = new.y / w;
                new.z = new.z / w;

Comment: above, you can see how i made the w. Do you have any example how to use these methods ? Thanks

Comment: i create a SCNVector4 and i have a SCNMatrix4. Now how can i make a this operation : SCNMatrix4 * SCNVector4 ?